# nodejs/express testing

Tags: javascript, unit-testing, asynchronous, node.js

I'm writing an app with express.

The main file is called **server.js**

one of the objects is

```
var app = express.createServer(express.logger(),
    express.bodyDecoder());
```

then I have

```
app.get("/",function(req, res){
  res.send("Running");
}
```

How do I use expresso, [or any other testing framework for that
matter], to test the routes output?

I looked at the expresso site, but couldn't figure out how to get it
to all work together, is it possible if someone gave me a short
example?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm sure you have found the answer to this by now but have you tried something like this:

```
assert.response(server, {
    url: '/',
    method: 'GET'
},{
    body: '{"name":"tj"}',
    status: 200,
    headers: {
        'Content-Type': 'application/json; charset=utf8',
        'X-Foo': 'bar'
    }
});
```

Comment: I've been considering writing a test suite based on NodeJS assert recently. Would you recommend doing so? I mean doing so would reduce the number of dependencies in my project... It also looks as though it might be easier, and more flexible.

Comment: If you can write a decent test suite using only assert then that is great.  That being said, Mocha as a dependency is pretty lightweight and gives you a lot of cool features.

Answer (score 2):

If you're new to Node.js and getting confused with all the different testing libs:

Expresso's successor is [Mocha](http://visionmedia.github.com/mocha/). In Mocha, you use a separate tool for HTTP response testing, such as [Request](https://github.com/mikeal/request/), [SuperTest](https://github.com/visionmedia/supertest#example), [zombie.js](http://zombie.labnotes.org/), etc.

Zombie.js seems the easiest to learn how to use, esp. w/ cookies and cookie-based sessions. It "maintains state across requests: history, cookies, HTML5 local and session stroage, etc."